# How to use Gumroad's listener to redirect to url from their overlay

Tags: javascript

Gumroad shared [the following code](https://blog.gumroad.com/post/186842238393/listen-for-purchases-within-the-gumroad-overlay) to listen for purchases being made within the Gumroad overlay:

```
listener = function(ev) {
       if (ev.data && JSON.parse(ev.data).post_message_name == “sale”) {
         document.getElementById(‘post-message-data’).innerHTML = ev.data;
       }
     }
     window.addEventListener('message’, listener, false);
```

As they say it can be used to redirect to a custom url (e.g. thank you page) after the purchase is complete. What code shall I add to do the redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect the page with:

```
window.location.href = 'http://example.com';
```

In your case, add it at the end of the callback function, like this:

```
listener = function(ev) {
       if (ev.data && JSON.parse(ev.data).post_message_name == “sale”) {
         document.getElementById(‘post-message-data’).innerHTML = ev.data;
         window.location.href = 'http://example.com';
       }
     }
     window.addEventListener('message’, listener, false);
```

Comment: Thank you, I also found this solution but unfortunately it does not work. Tried to replace the page redirection with a simple alert (alert("test") but it was not triggered either. I guess there might be something wrong with the code provided by Gumroad, I'll have to check it with their support.

Comment: @kurblivas If the eventlistener's callback is not being executed, it's possible that the event is not being properly fired, or that the eventlistener is added to the wrong element. However, this is something that you'd better ask their support about. Good luck.